# Dismiss spinner control popup if you don't want an item in android

Tags: spinner, android

I have an android spinner which I call via the performClick method to show a list of items (the actual control is hidden from the user and is called from a checkbox, too complex to explain why I have done it this way).

If I do not want an item in the list, how can I dismiss the popup by clicking on the black area?

Does this make sense? :/

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention that the users will not be able to operate the bottom buttons (device is going to be galaxy tab) as they will be covered up with protective layer due as they will be outdoors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually such a control is dismissed using the back key in the android applications. So I would suggest that you find a way to do it the same way on your control.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the users will not be able to operate the bottom buttons (device is going to be galaxy tab) as they will be covered up with protective layer due as they will be outdoors.

Comment: Then I think the easiest would simply be to add a "cancel" button to your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

'Esc' button should do the same job..

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the users will not be able to operate the bottom buttons (device is going to be galaxy tab) as they will be covered up with protective layer due as they will be outdoors.

Comment: How about adding 'Select' as an item in the item list?If the user do not want any actual item in the list, they can click on 'Select' itself  which  can  take them back.